# JSTL - Which jstl element to use for multiline text?

Tags: java, jstl

I am creating an email client. Which element can I use for the body of the email? It will contain special characters, newlines etc.

Is it proper to use `form:input`, or is there any other element specifically for this purpose?

Comment: form:input doesn't have anything to do with the JSTL. The JSTL doesn't contain any tag for HTML elements.

Comment: Do you mean Spring instead of JSTL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Spring form tags, you can use `form:textarea`.

```
<form:textarea path="notes" rows="3" cols="20" />
```